# I have an RS485 output but I don't know which character set it is using

Tags: serial-port, rs485

The output string is:

`````
▒~▒▒~▒▒~▒▒~▒▒~▒▒~▒▒~▒▒~▒▒~▒▒~▒▒~▒▒~▒▒~▒▒~▒▒~▒▒~▒▒~▒▒~▒▒~▒▒~▒▒ffx▒f▒x▒x`▒x▒x▒x▒`▒x~x▒▒x▒▒x````▒````▒x~xx▒x▒f`▒x▒
`````

And I know that over RS232 the output should look similar to:

```
ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿSITE NAME,24/07/18,13:15:00,60,0.000,0.000,2.911,2585,
```

The time may change, as well as the last two numbers but the rest of the string should be consistent. Is there a way to figure out the character set that was used?

Comment: Is your baud rate on your system correct?

Comment: Yes the baud rate is correct at 19200

Comment: As @EastonBornemeier stated, usually when you see garbage like this, it's almost always a baud rate issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is written in [RS-485 Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-485) as follows.

> Protocols
>   RS-485 is not a protocol; it's simply an electrical interface. Although many applications use RS-485 signal levels, the speed, format, and protocol of the data transmission is not specified by RS-485. Interoperability of even similar devices from different manufacturers is not assured by compliance with the signal levels alone.

If the specifications of the device you are trying to connect are not documented, you only have to look it up with a measuring instrument such as an oscilloscope?

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem might be having selected the wrong baud rate. Check your manual!